# A strange operation problem in SQL Server: -100/-100*10 = 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, operator-precedence

- If you execute `SELECT -100/-100*10` the result is `0`.
- If you execute `SELECT (-100/-100)*10` the result is `10`.
- If you execute `SELECT -100/(-100*10)` the result is `0`.
- If you execute `SELECT 100/100*10` the result is `10`.

[BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states:

> When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the expression.

And

```
Level   Operators
  1     ~ (Bitwise NOT)
  2     * (Multiplication), / (Division), % (Modulus)
  3     + (Positive), - (Negative), + (Addition), + (Concatenation), - (Subtraction), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)
```

Is BOL wrong, or am I missing something? It seems the `-` is throwing the (expected) precedence off.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do you think you have to do with bits, you are working with integers. And integer/integer = integer. So -100/-1000 is 0

Comment: why is not -100/-100*10 = (-100/-100)*10 = 10

Comment: Maybe you wanted a decimal as the answer? -100./-100*10, here -100. is decimal and the result is decimal

Comment: -100/-100*10 = -100/-(100*10) = 0,  * (Multiplication) then - (Negative) then / (Division)

Comment: Without any explicit convertions, any constants like 100 are treated as integer. I don't understand what do you expect as the result. The result of division between integers is also integer

Comment: If we extrapolate this out: `-100/-100*10 = -100/(-100*10) = -100/-1000 = 0` . Why is `-100/-1000=0`? Because you have `int` datatypes and the "actual" value (`0.1`), cannot be represented by a integer value. As a result the decimal points are lost: `0.1->0`. If you need decimal places, you need to use decimals. For example `-100/-100*10.0 = 0.10000000`

Comment: I know why is not 0.1，I want to know why is not  10 。。

Comment: Because maths, @cuizizhe ... `-100/-1000` is `0.1`. That's how maths works. Why would you expect `-100/-1000` to ever be `10`? Whenever you divide a number by a larger (absolute) number you **always** end up with a number with a smaller (abolsulte) number than you started with. That's basic maths I'm afraid, and how it's always worked for many centuries/millenia.

Comment: @Larnu, please see my edits, I think OP is asking about the precedence of execution. It's not an illogical question, I think.

Comment: if that is what they are asking, that makes things more clear, and I'm happy to vote to reopen.

Comment: OK, I do agree, that `-` does seem to be causing the flow to go "wrong". If you try `-100/(-100)*10` you get the result `10`. it seems that the `/` is being applied against to value `-` in the equation and then the equation `100*10` is being determined. I'm not sure this is an error with BOL, but more that SQL Server isn't behaving as expected. It might be worth raising an issue on [sql-docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues) and seeing what their response is there; perhaps a note could be added to the documentation advising of the "feature".

Comment: `SELECT -100/(-100)*10` also returns 10. It looks like `-` is treated as the `-` operator which should be applied only after `100*10` is calculated

Comment: There are operators from two different levels: 1:) `*`, `/` and 2) `-`.  So what is evaluated is SELECT -100/-(100*10), not what OP expects (-100/-100)*10.

Comment: @Zhorov that's not the problem here. `-100/-100` has the same precedence as multiplication.

Comment: I would actually suggest that this *shouldn't* be the expected behaviour. If you use variables, with the literal values you would expect the same results, but you don't [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d1ef4cf4e537ddb0485d605f1df38ab1). Personally, I recommend this raised as an issue on sql-docs as this is likely u̶n̶intended behaviour and thus needs to be documented.

Comment: @Larnu I've made the same test case. With variables everything works as expected.

Comment: So you're saying that you got `0` as well, @Zhorov? That's not the behaviour I get.

Comment: `A / -B * C` is `A <div> <negate> B <multiply> C`. Negate has lower precedence than multiply, per the docs, so the result is `A / -(B * C)`. You can see this more clearly by using floating constants: `12e / -13e * 14e` vs. `12e / (-13e) * 14e` vs `12e / 13e * 14e`.The reason this throws us off is because we generally expect unary minus to become part of the literal, or at least have very high precedence, but that's not how T-SQL works.

Comment: In SQLFiddle every database except SQL Server returns `10`. There's an [unanswered duplicate from 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263318/order-precedence-of-multiplication-and-division) too

Comment: You can run this query on [Data Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/975898/a-strange-operation-problem-in-sql-server--100-10010-0)

Comment: The really crazy thing, in my mind, is that `+` and `-` have high precedence than `*` and `/`. `5 + 2 * 10` should be `25`, not `70`.

Answer (score 96):

According to the precedence table, this *is* the expected behavior. The operator with higher precedence (`/` and `*`) is evaluated before operator with lower precedence (unary `-`). So this:

```
-100 / -100 * 10
```

is evaluated as:

```
-(100 / -(100 * 10))
```

Note that this behavior is different from most programming languages where unary negation has higher precedence than multiplication and division e.g. [VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence#precedence-order), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table).

Comment: Wow, another gem feature in T-SQL :) I guess I have to audit all of my code now to search for bugs.

Comment: oh man. This is even worse than the various PHP [ternary operator bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22633643/995714) https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61915. What sane people think that unary operators must have lower precedence than binary ones?

Comment: @phuclv: well, `-` has the same precedence whether it's unary or binary, so it's a form of consistency, you see? I'm actually surprised it "works" as often as it does; there aren't too many expressions where you could actually notice the difference. Which, of course, makes it extra insidious. (Regarding sanity: there are multiple places where the T-SQL parser demonstrably takes shortcuts, whether out of carelessness, laziness or misplaced efficiency concerns, that lead to odd/unintuitive results, this might be one of those. At least this one is actually documented.)

Comment: The real difference may be whether `-` is considered an operator in `-100`. In some languages, it's part of the syntax of an integer.

Comment: So it's a bug in their precedence of unary `-`.

Comment: @phuclv there is a classic example of `-3^2` (a mix of unary and binary). A mathematician will tell you that it should be _-9_ i.e. `-(3^2)` (see BODMAS rules), a programmer will tell you that it should be _9_ i.e. `(-3)^2`.

Comment: This is integer division so 100 / -1000 truncates, and that's the last step to get 0 instead of something else?

Comment: @JeroenMostert are there parser bugs? I was under the impression they were using a parser generator. That's why the syntax error message is so generic. It's always "syntax error near ...".

Comment: `-(100 / -(100 * 10))` -> `-(100 / -(1000))` -> `-(100 / -1000)` -> `-(-0.1)` -> `0.1` = `0`?

Comment: @Salman no, programmers still say that -3^2 = -9 because power has higher precedence in most languages (if they have it) with some weird exceptions like excel

Comment: And the winner of counter-intuitive design is ...: Microsoft - once more

Comment: @phuclv agreed. The point I was trying to make is that a unary operator does not need to have higher precedence all the time (see -3^2 in vb.net). In JavaScript for example you have `delete window.foo`... it is evaluated as `delete (window.foo)` and not `(delete window).foo` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @phuclv: Microsoft just ensures consistency across their products, like [Why does =-x^2+x for x=3 in Excel result in 12](https://superuser.com/questions/1385570/why-does-x2x-for-x-3-in-excel-result-in-12-instead-of-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 34):

BOL is correct. `-` has lower precedence than `*`, so

```
-A * B
```

is parsed as

```
-(A * B)
```

Multiplication being what it is, you don't typically notice this, except when mixing in the two other binary operators with equal precedence: `/` and `%` (and `%` is rarely used in compound expressions like this). So

```
C / -A * B
```

Is parsed as

```
C / -(A * B)
```

explaining the results. This is counter-intuitive because in most other languages, unary minus has higher precedence than `*` and `/`, but not in T-SQL, and this is documented correctly.

A nice (?) way to illustrate it:

```
SELECT -1073741824 * 2
```

produces an arithmetic overflow, because `-(1073741824 * 2)` produces `2147483648` as an intermediate, which does not fit in an `INT`, but

```
SELECT (-1073741824) * 2
```

produces the expected result `-2147483648`, which does.

Comment: "minus" is binary. Unary `-` is "negative". People who say things like "minus 10" when they mean "negative 10" are being imprecise.

Comment: @Acccumulation: the imprecision isn't mine. The `-` operator, when applied to a single operand, is called `MINUS` in SQL query plans. Its binary counterpart is called `SUB`. If you like, interpret "unary minus" as shorthand for "the unary operator signified by the minus sign" -- a syntactic rather than a semantic designation.

Comment: "negative 10" is standard American usage (I believe) but it is not standard in the UK.

Answer (score 12):

Notice in the documentation that (perhaps counter-intuitively) the order of precedence for `- (Negative)` is third.

So you effectively get:

`-(100/-(100*10)) = 0`

If you place them into variables you won't see this happening, as there is no unary operation that occurs after the multiplication.

So here A and B are the same, whereas C, D, E show the result you are seeing (with E having the complete bracketing)

```
DECLARE @i1 int, @i2 int, @i3 int;

SELECT @i1 = -100,
       @i2 = -100,
       @i3 = 10;

SELECT @i1/@i2*@i3      [A],
       -100/(-100)*10   [B],
       -100/-100*10     [C],
       -100/-(100*10)   [D],
       -(100/-(100*10)) [E];

A - 10
B - 10
C - 0
D - 0
E - 0
```