# What is the difference between XOR in parenthesis and without in C language

Tags: c

i have some code and it checking chechsum by XOR on 5 first numbers, and it should be equal to the sixth number. But, what is the difference between

```
if (n0^n1^n2^n3^n4==n5)  return true;
    else return false;
```

and

```
if ((n0^n1^n2^n3^n4)==n5)  return true;
    else return false;
```

?

Because the first one is working and the second one is not.

Comment: In the first one the operands of `==` are `n4` and `n5`

Comment: Look up "operator precedence".

Comment: So... why when I have n0=1E, n1=00, n2=ED, n3=E5, n4=E5, n5=F3 it is true when there is no parenthesis? And false with parenthesis

Comment: You say the first one is working, but actually the second one is right.  That means whatever is calculating the checksum that you later check is wrong.

Comment: See [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 4):

The C grammar establishes operator precedence with `==` having higher precedence than `^`. So `n0^n1^n2^n3^n4==n5` is equivalent to `n0^n1^n2^n3^(n4==n5)`, which differs from `(n0^n1^n2^n3^n4)==n5`.

[This is regarded by Kernighan and Ritchie and others as a mistake in the design of the C language, which occurred due to the history of its development.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733581/which-operators-in-c-have-wrong-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

[C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of operator `==` is higher than the precedence of the operator `^`. Therefore in the first case the C compiler first executes `n4==n5` which either results in `1`or `0` and then it will do all xor operators between `n0..n3` and the result of the comparison.

In the second case the precedence of the () is higher than '=='. So, all xor operators will be done first and the comparison will be done the last.

It explains the difference in your program results.

Comment: (added link to C Operator Precedence table)