# Different results from similar T-SQL queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Two t-SQL (MS SQL 2017) queries:

```
Select 125. /  -124/ 125.
Select 125. / (-124)/125.
```

Difference only on parentheses.

But, results are not equal:

```
-126.0080645161
-0.0080645120
```

Why the results are different?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513450/a-strange-operation-problem-in-sql-server-100-10010-0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is that in T-SQL, the `* (Multiplication)` and `/ (Division)` operators have higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) than the `- (Negative)` operator. So what is exactly evaluated is:

Expession 1: `125. / - (124 / 125)` , equals to : `-126.0080645161`

Expession 2:  `125. / (-124) / 125` , equals to : `-0.0080645120`

Note, that the correct result is: `-0.0080645120`.

Comment: The operator is unary negative https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/unary-operators-negative?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 4):

The addition of the parentheses in the second case is changing the order of operations.  To avoid any ambiguity, you should specify parentheses explicitly.  For the first result, you should use:

```
SELECT 125. / (-124 / 125.)
```

and for the second case:

```
SELECT (125. / -124) / 125.
```

Comment: Amen. Know the precedence rules. Write code that is clear and easily understood. Even if not needed, the parentheses make clear the intent.